# Java weird generic's behavior

Tags: java, generics

I found some weird behavior for java generics. I can't use parametrized class, which implements another parametrized class, in parametrized method.
It sounds messy, so let's look at the code:

```
class A {
    public<RESP extends Serializable, REQ extends Serializable> RESP sendData(REQ req, Class<? extends I<RESP, REQ>> c) {
        return null;
    }
}

interface I<RESP extends Serializable, REQ extends Serializable> {
}

class B implements I<String, Integer> {
    A a;
    public void test() {
        a.sendData(1, getClass());
    }
}
```

It compiles fine. But we can break it easily. Just add a parameter variable to class B:

```
class B<T> implements I<String, Integer>
```

Now `a.sendData(1, B.class);` has the compiler error:

```
method sendData in class A cannot be applied to given types;
required: REQ,Class<? extends I<RESP,REQ>>
found: int,Class<B>
reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) RESP,REQ
(argument mismatch; Class<B> cannot be converted to Class<? extends I<RESP,REQ>>)
where REQ,RESP are type-variables:
REQ extends Serializable declared in method <RESP,REQ>sendData(REQ,Class<? extends I<RESP,REQ>>)
RESP extends Serializable declared in method <RESP,REQ>sendData(REQ,Class<? extends I<RESP,REQ>>)
```

I just added unused parameter to class signature! 
Can anyone explain why this happens and is there way to use type variable in class B? 
Actualy my goal is signature for class B like this:
`class B<Data> implements I<String, ? extends List<Data>>`

By the way, I try this code in Java 8.

Comment: *"Now a.sendData(1, B.class); has the compiler error"* That is not the same code. `B.class` is not the same as `getClass()`. Please compare apples to apples. `B.class` returns a `Class<B>`, while `getClass()` returns a `Class<?>`.

Comment: @Andreas `getClass` actually returns a `Class<? extends B>`

Comment: The situation changed when you made B generic, because before, it wasn't. As B wasn't generic, there was no cause for concern for potentially missing type parameters when using the type B, as the type B doesn't has type parameters. So, when referencing type B, everything is fine and well-defined, and the compiler sees that it is a subtype of I<String, Integer>, which complies with the expected types. Now that you made B generic with <T>, referencing type B as-is means referencing type B without specifying its type parameters. Therefore the compiler can't check the type parameters involved.

Comment: So there is no way to fix this? I Can do some dirty tricks with casting and Object, but I loose type safety...

Comment: I mean, the generics system has limitations. Just cast to (Class<B<?>>)

Comment: It works, but I can't do the same if I use type variable in signature `class B<T> implements I<String, ArrayList<T>>` which is my final goal.

Comment: @kumesana Do you know where this behaviour is specified in the JLS?

Comment: @Quaffel The JLS sometimes justifies what it mandates, but often doesn't. Its role is to state the rules, not to explain itself on why these rules are like so. Anyway, I'd say the most relevant part is the definition of Raw Types, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8 . With the sentence "The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type. "

Comment: @judent cast to (Class<B<T>>) then. I was using B<?> to limit the rules bending we were doing, but as we are rule bending we'll have to bend them as much as is needed.

Comment: There is no point in discussing the scenario where `B`’s supertype is not related to `B`’s type parameter when your final goal is to make it related anyway. This won’t work. Or well, the crucial point is what you are planning to do with the `Class` object in `sendData`, as the `Class` object does not contain information about the type parameters of non-reifiable types.

Comment: @kumesana I know that the JLS doesn't have to justify the rules it sets, although it does quite often. I was just curious which rule applies here. Nonetheless, thank you for the clarification and the reference!